# A resource of MySQL Datatypes to check against a string

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a resource of MySQL data types (varchar, int...) available in PHP?

Or perhaps a function that checks if a string is a valid MySQL data type?

If not is there a CSV list somewhere that could be copy/pasted into a project without having to manually enter every single datatype (there are about 40 different types)?

I am creating a database helper class and I would like to check a string against a list of valid MySQL data types.

Comment: No offence please, but if you place it on your blog or as a gist, it would equally work as well and it won't influence your karama here on stackoverflow. As long as you place it here, you have to accept that you can risk down or upvotes. That's just it. Complaining afterwards seems a little mood.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but this just doesn't meet the requirements for a question and will probably be removed... regardless of your good intentions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Honestly, IMO, the only thing wrong with this post is that it doesn't seem useful at all. Why would anyone need this? How could this possibly be useful to anyone.

Comment: Maybe if you posted what you were actually doing someone might find use in it.

Comment: yes. thank you. I just altered the question to hopefully be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This would have been very helpful to have found something like this for quick copy/paste. I thought I would post it as someone else might find it useful. If I am missing anything please let me know.

```
array('CHAR','VARCHAR','TINYTEXT','TEXT','BLOB','MEDIUMTEXT','TINYBLOB','MEDIUMBLOB','BLOB','LONGBLOB','LONGTEXT','TINYINT','SMALLINT','MEDIUMINT','INT','BIGINT','FLOAT','DOUBLE','DECIMAL','REAL','BIT','BOOLEAN','SERIAL','BINARY','VARBINARY','DATE','DATETIME','TIMESTAMP','TIME','YEAR','ENUM ','SET','GEOMETRY','POINT','LINESTRING','POLYGON','MULTIPOINT','MULTILINESTRING','MULTIPOLYGON','GEOMETRYCOLLECTION');
```

here is the function I was using it in:

```
function isValidDatatype($datatype){
    $mysqlDatatypes = array('CHAR','VARCHAR','TINYTEXT','TEXT','BLOB','MEDIUMTEXT','TINYBLOB','MEDIUMBLOB','BLOB','LONGBLOB','LONGTEXT','TINYINT','SMALLINT','MEDIUMINT','INT','BIGINT','FLOAT','DOUBLE','DECIMAL','REAL','BIT','BOOLEAN','SERIAL','BINARY','VARBINARY','DATE','DATETIME','TIMESTAMP','TIME','YEAR','ENUM ','SET','GEOMETRY','POINT','LINESTRING','POLYGON','MULTIPOINT','MULTILINESTRING','MULTIPOLYGON','GEOMETRYCOLLECTION');
    return in_array($datatype,$mysqlDatatypes);
}
```

Comment: can this be easily grabbed from phpmyadmin? I cant seem to see this. I got my list from there actually... but the datatypes are in a dropdown list. not exactly easy to copy/past for other usage.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The point is, it's bad practice to dynamically generate and alter tables unless youre writing an install script. you should be building your tables with mysql alone (like via pma or cli), not with hand-written php.

Comment: I am writing an install script. I guess I am being overly thorough checking if the input is valid as it technically will be a static input from my script. I am just building a helper class and trying to be as thorough as possible

Comment: I still feel like there is a better way, but since you have a use case.. there is no need for an If statement, `in_array()` already returns a bool. You can just `return in_array($datatype,$mysqlDatatypes);` That will work exactly the same way.